# Django: Prevent form fields being cleared when invalid data entered

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following form, which allows a user to submit a file and email address.

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.validators import validate_email

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    file = forms.FileField()

class EmailField(forms.CharField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'invalid': _(u'Enter a valid e-mail address.'),
    }
    default_validators = [validate_email]
```

Here's the view:

```
def upload_file(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            handle_uploaded_file(email, request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload_file.html', {'form': form},   
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If the user submits the form with an invalid email, the form is displayed back to the user, but the fields are cleared. What's the correct way to prevent this clearing of form fields?

Comment: Not clearing the fields is django's default behaviour. I set up a dummy project using your view and form code... the form displayed back to the user after an error doesn't have the fields cleared, so everything you've posted seems to work as is on a stock install of django 1.2.

Comment: But it does clear them for me using the above. I'm using Django 1.2.1. What could cause this on mine but not yours?

Answer (score 2):

Silly mistake. Updated my template to include the form values. All working now.